# How can I rename files in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line

How would I rename a file, say `old.txt` to `new.txt`, in Linux using shell commands?

Comment: rename actually is a Linux command for renaming, though for a single file mv is used.  rename is typically for batch renames.

Answer (score 12):

`mv old.txt new.txt`

Answer (score 1):

mv is a command that "moves" the file given as the first argument to the name specified in the second.  In this case, you're just moving the file from one name to another in the same directory.